# How do I implement recursive mergesort for items in a text

Tags: c, recursion, mergesort

I have the text "DIRESTRAITS" which in my task i hade to do recursive Mergesort on. In the task i am reffered to this code:

```
void mergesort (itemType a[], int l, int r)
{
 int i,j,k,m;
 if (r>l)
 {
  m = (r+l)/2;
  mergesort(a,l,m);
  mergesort(a,m+l,r);
  for (i = m+1; i > l; i--) b[i--] = a[i-1]
  for (j = m; j < r; j++) b[r+m-j] = a[j+1];
  for (k = 1; k <= r; k++)
   a[k] = (b[i]<=b[j]& i<= m) ? b[i++] : b[j--];
 }
}
```

thats the code i get in the task text. The task tells me to draw every time the 3rd for loop is done, and mark the keys that have been involved. here is the answer (i need help to understand the code above):

```
   Start:   
            D I R E S T R A I T S
            D I
            D I R
                  E S
                  E S T
            D E I R S T
                        A R
                        A I R
                              S T
                        A I R S T
   Finish:  A D E I I R R S S T T
```

Answer (score 1):

The example code is faulty, such as the second parameter in the second recursive call to mergesort should be m + one, not m + L . I'm not sure what else is broken in the example code.

A top down merge sort recursively splits the array into sub-arrays until the sub-array size is 1 (or zero). No merging (sorting) of data is performed until a pair of sub-arrays of size 1 are produced by the recursive splitting of arrays. Then since an array of size 1 can be considered sorted, left and right sub-arrays are merged creating a sorted sub-array of size 2, then those sorted sub-arrays are later merged to form larger sorted sub-arrays.  This process follows the recursive call chain down (splitting) and up (merging) until the entire array is sorted (depth first, left first).

A working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/*                   012345678901234 */
static char a[16] = "DIRESTRAITS    ";
static char b[16] = "               ";

void mergesort (char a[], int l, int r)
{
int i,j,k,m;
    if (r>l)
    {
        m = (r+l)/2;
        mergesort(a,l,m);
        mergesort(a,m+1,r);
        for (i = l; i <= r; i++)b[i] = a[i];
        i = l;
        j = m+1;
        for (k = l; k <= r; k++)
            a[k] = (j > r || i <= m && b[i] <= b[j]) ? b[i++] : b[j++];
        for (k = 0; k < l; k++)
            printf("  ");
        for (k = l; k <= r; k++)
            printf("%c ", a[k]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
int k;
    for(k = 0; k <= 10; k++)
        printf("%c ", a[k]);
    printf("\n");
    mergesort(a, 0, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mergesort, as the name suggests, is based on merging: combining two sorted lists into one.  The algorithm divides the list to be sorted into two (roughyly) halves, and sorts each half (this is done by the recursive calls to `merge sort`).  The next two loops each copy half of the results from array `a` into array `b`; the last loop re-fills `a` from `b`, walking along the two halves of `b` and, at each step, taking the smaller of the two (or, once one half has ben used up, just taking it form the other) for the next value to go into `a`.

Comment: thankyou, hopefully i can finnish this chapter now (which only base on this code) thanks alot! :)

Comment: If Scott's answer solved your problem, please select the answer by clicking on the checkmark beneath the number at the top-left of his answer.